# Использования кнопки

Tags: php

Есть кнопка:

```
<INPUT type="button" title="<?php echo $row['atk_1']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['atk_1']; ?>" onclick="location.href='/game.php?page=def'"  style="width:80px; background-color: #A6CAF0; border: 1px solid";>
```

Как в `'/game.php?page=def'` Вывести значения кнопки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вообще-то в данном примере никак.
т.к. не отправляется форма с нужными параметрами, а пользователь просто переходит по клику по ссылке.**

Это и есть ответ на твой вопрос.

Либо переписать

```
<INPUT type="button" title="<?=$row['atk_1'];?>" onclick="location.href='/game.php?page=def&value=<?=$row['atk_1'];?>'" >
```

Ну и в **game.php**

```
Echo $_GET['value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

вот в этой части

```
onclick="location.href='/game.php?page=def
```

передать название кнопки в GET запросе.. Что-то типо такого

```
onclick="location.href='/game.php?page=def&button_name="<?php echo $row['atk_1']; ?>"
```

Тогда в game.php значение кнопки будет доступно в $_GET['button_name']

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить атрибут name в тег кнопки. В game.php:

```
$_REQUEST['имя кнопки']
```

Лучше фильтровать по методам запроса `$_POST`, `$_GET`...